# Self injecting prototype bean - cyclic reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I need to self-inject prototype bean. 
As I know, it is possible if bean scope="singleton", but in this case I get message from spring : "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle: postMan2"

My bean:

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class PostMan2 implements PostMans2 {

    private PostMans2 postman;

    @Async
    public Future<String> deliverLetter(String message, int i) {
        postman.test();
        String res = "result!";
        return new AsyncResult<String>(res);
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Self injection example thread name="+name);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        postman = ctx.getBean(PostMans2.class);
    }

}
```

Invoking:

```
@Service
public class PostOffice implements PostOffices {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void creatingPostmans() {
        PostMans2 thr = ctx.getBean(PostMans2.class);
        Future<String> fut = thr.deliverLetter("Some letter", 100);
        while (!fut.isDone()) {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("ending of PostMan's jobs...");

    }


}
```

How to improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `init()` is forming a Cycle.

When you call this in `PostOffice` class

```
PostMans2 thr = ctx.getBean(PostMans2.class);
```

`PostMans2` class will be refered.

In `PostMans2` you have defined `init()` which will again refer `PostMans2` and this will go on

So try removing `init()` from `PostMan2` and all should be fine

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    postman = ctx.getBean(PostMans2.class);
}
```

Comment: you didn't understand. I deliberately use cyclic reference. but problem is why I can't use it in prototype beans?

Comment: Well its like you are telling A to Call B and B to Call A .  This process will never end. So spring is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to go through Spring to get instance of **this**?

Looks like what you want to do it this:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    postman = this;
}
```